# style data loaded from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, css, sql

I have a list where a user can add a contact. A number list. Every time i add a record number, I want to add to the list with a `fade` by css transiton.

I wrote this code :

```
while($record=mysql_fetch_array($selectResult))
    {
        $cont++;
        if($record["T_id"]!=""){
            //echo $record["T_id"]." - ".$record[1]." - ".$record[2]."<br>";
            echo '<div class="numRecord" id="Numrecord-'.$cont.'" style="opacity:1">
                  <p class="recordCont">'.$cont.' -</p>
                  <p class="recordName">'.$record["T_name"].'</p>
                  <p class="recordNum">'.$record["T_prenumber"].'-'.$record["T_number"].'</p>
                  <a href="edit.php?edit=edit" id="edit-'.$cont.'">Edit</a>
                  <a href="edit.php?edit=del&&id='.$record["T_id"].'" id="delet-'.$record["T_id"].'">Delete</a>
              </div>';

        }else{
            echo "Nothing to show"; 
        }
    }
```

and the css is :

```
.numRecord {
    position:relative;
    border:1px dotted rgba(0,0,0,0.63); 
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
    margin:5px 0 5px 0;
    -webkit-transition:1s all ease;
    -moz-transition:1s all ease;
    -o-transition:1s all ease;
    -ms-transition:1s all ease;
    transition:1s all ease;
    opacity:0;
}
```

But the transition doesn't work :( ...

Comment: The first thing I would recommend is to stop using the deprecated mysql functions. Switch to [mysqli](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) at a minimum, and switch to [PDO](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) if you want real security and long-term stability.

Comment: Do you want a smooth transition where the new record is added to the existing page without a refresh?  Or are you looking for new divs to slide into place WHEN the page refreshes?

Comment: yes i want when refresh divs slide

Comment: and what is different between mysql and mysqli ?

Comment: and if i want to exiting page whitout refrresh?